# Detectar ou bloquear redirecionamento com ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tento um problema numa requisição ajax que estou fazendo.

A url requisitada é uma url `x`, porém, quando faço a requisição, ela me redireciona para uma url `y`.

Estou usando a função `$.ajax` do jQuery.

Gostaria de saber se tem como detectar pelo jQuery que a url requisitada sofreu um redirecionamento. Ou interromper esse redirecionamento, informando um erro.

Como o redirecionamento não conta como erro, está dando problema na forma com que trato os dados, quer dizer, mesmo com o redirecionamento, a requisição chama o `success`.

Comment: Possui algum código de exemplo, amigo? Fica um pouco difícil compreender o seu cenário com exatidão

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acredito que não seja possível detectar se o servidor redirecionou a sua requisição AJAX, o que pode ser feito é adicionar um Header no servidor informando a URL processada, então você compara este header com a url enviada...

Comment: Nossa @VictorAlencarSantos precisa ser mais específico? Como vou demonstrar um redirecionamento com código? Tudo que pude explicar já está na pergunta

Comment: Um jeito de driblar isso é enviar a requisição ajax para o seu proprio servidor. Então no lado server o CURL faria a requisição. A lógica nisso é que o CURL detecta redirecionamentos. O problema é o consumo de tráfego de dados e processos no servidor só para fazer isso. Mas, de qualquer forma, se for algo tão importante, está aí uma gambiarra funcional.

Comment: @DanielOmine é uma jogada boa. Mas no meu caso fazer isso daria quase que na mesma, seria o sistema fazendo requisição para o mesmo sistema para depois retornar para o cliente.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não posso fornecer uma resposta detalhada agora, mas posso dizer **que é impossível** detectar em Ajax ou requisições normais o redirecionamento, o único que sabe que houve redirecionamento é a *interface* de requisições interna do navegador.

Seria algo como:

[image: Interface do navegador]

- Interface do usuário:

  É a camada renderizada, aonde já tem a resposta pronta ou parcial, a tela do navegador (conhecido como webView)
- Interface de requisições e respostas:

  É uma interface interna que responde somente ao browser e gerencia todas requisições HTTP, fica responsável por resolver um servidor, enviar a requisição para o mesmo e pegar a resposta, em caso de redirecionamento ele envia uma nova requisição.
- Servidor HTTP:

  É um site, domínio, local ou não que é acessível através de um endereço e suas respostas são headers seguidos de textos ou dados binários que "nada fazem" (pois o responsável por interpretar isto é a interface de requisições e respostas).

Quando ocorre um redirecionamentos `301`, `302`, etc, quem vai gerenciar isto é a *Interface de requisições e respostas*, a única ferramenta que enxerga isto é o depurador do navegador (no Chrome aperte o F12 do teclado que irá exibir o depuradir).

### Como resolver

A única maneira é mudar a abordagem, ou seja ao invés de redirecionar no back-end, mudar para o front-end e fazer algo semelhante ao que colocou na sua própria resposta, respostas json ou xml com "comandos" que dizem o que fazer e até criar seus próprios códigos de erro customizados, assim:

- Exemplo de código de erro (as resposta HTTP sempre será `200 Ok`)

  ```
  { "status": 5000, "message": "Erro na requisição" }
  ```
- Exemplo de código de sucesso

  ```
  { "status": 1000, "message": "Cadastrado com sucesso" }
  ```
- Exemplo de código de redirecionamento no front-end

  ```
  { "status": 9000, "message": null, "url": "/path/route" }
  ```

O código ficaria algo como:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "/route/page",
  method: "GET",
  data: { id : 1 },
  dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(data) {
     if (data.status === 9000) {//Detecta redirecionamento
        window.location = data.url; //Redireciona (se quiser :) )
     } else {
        //...Código segue fluxo normal
     }
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

> **Nota:** Penso que talvez você tenha pensando em fazer uma requisição no servidor, até funcionaria, mas acho que além de ser mais uma gambiarra, seria bastante custoso para o servidor conforme aumentasse o numero de usuários acessando ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Never gambiarra in my code

Comment: @WallaceMaxters só o meu desenho que não ficou bom, mas no fim de semana eu faço um "mais correto" :)

Answer (score 2):

Fui atrás de uma fonte para ver se posso resolver não só o meu problema.

Todo redirecionamento, geralmente trás como código de resposta `301` e `302`. Quando a resposta retorna correta o status é `200`.

Estou falando para entenderem o que encontrei [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589) no SOEN.

> Na verdade, você não tem a capacidade de detectar se uma resposta 302
>   ocorreu. Se o redirecionamento 302 leva a um 200, então o seu programa
>   atua de forma idêntica como se o pedido inicial levou diretamente a um
>   200.

Ou seja, o ajax é "enganado", por assim dizer, por um redirecionamento, atuando como se a redirecionamento fosse um comportamento esperado para retornar sucesso na requisição XHTTPRequest.

O máximo que pode ser feito nesse caso é: Se você requisita uma url `x` esperando receber dados json por exemplo, e é redirecionado para uma url `y`, como é o meu caso, você pode tratar isso verificando se encontrou os dados esperados pelo `json` na sua chamada de sucesso da requisição ajax.

Exemplo:

URL X

```
 {"message":"Cadastrado com sucesso"}
```

URL Y é a página inicial da minha aplicação

Requisição AJAX

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/x',
     success: function (response)
     {
           if (response.message) {
               return alert('Dados esperados foram retornados');
           }

           alert('Ocorreu um erro! Dados incosistentes')
     }
})
```

Comment: isso que você postou não é a solução do problema descrito por você.

Comment: Ninguem está discutindo, estamos vendo a melhor solução.

Comment: Solucionou o meu problema.

Comment: Não é que o ajax é enganado, é que faltou (desculpe a sinceridade) você entender a camada da Resposta no navegadores, os navegadores é que recebem a resposta em um nivel mais profundo e só entregam a tela a resposta final. Ajax é nada mais que uma requisição normal em uma camada aonde o javascript poderá controlar e setar em variáveis valores de respostas. Se notar mesmo em requisições normais (sem ajax) você não irá conseguir detectar o redirecionamento. O que falta é entender é a camada http para o usuário final :)

Comment: O ajax "é enganado" foi apenas uma expressão tosca. Eu entendo como funciona as paradas (quando abrimos o console do chrome dá pra ver que a url é redirecionada 3 vezes). Se o ajax vai pegar a resposta final, então obviamente, se não ocorrer um erro na resposta final, retornará ok