# Quando somo uma variável que passei de JS para PHP ela soma

Tags: php, javascript

Eu consigo passar a variável de JS para PHP, porem quando tento somar ela simplesmente some.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;
    </script>
</head>

    <?php $width = '<script>document.write(width);</script>';
    $php = $width + 10;

    echo $php;
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Para que isso ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo preciso do tamanho da tela em uma variável PHP.

Comment: Leia [*Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-c%C3%B3digo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web/612#612)

Comment: Mas para que ? Talvez tenha outras maneiras de fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Quando o servidor fez a soma a variavel em JS não existia ainda, pois é tratada no cliente

Answer (score 13):

PHP é back-end e JavaScript é front-end.

O que o PHP faz é gerar uma página, podendo ser html, txt, imagem, etc, ou seja ele é executado no **servidor** antes de chegar ao teu navegador, já o JavasSript é executado no **navegador**.

Leia essas respostas, apesar do foco serem outras coisas, eu explico como funciona a interação **requisição** e **resposta**, recomendo que leia:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635

O que o servidor faz é enviar apenas a resposta do que o PHP gerou para o seu navegador, o PHP já foi executado e terminado, então não tem como o JavaScript se comunicar com o PHP a não ser que seja por Ajax (que é uma requisição em "background").

Quando você faz isso:

```
$width = '<script>document.write(width);</script>';
```

Você não está passando o valor de `width` para `$width`, na verdade o PHP está enxergando `<script>document.write(width);</script>` e não o valor `width`.

Não tem como o PHP saber na mesma requisição o valor do tamanho da tela, o que você pode fazer é usar Ajax, por exemplo:

Na sua página adicione isso na sua página:

```
<script>
(function ()
{
    function enviarTamanhoTela()
    {
        var querystring  = "largura=" + screen.width;
            querystring += "&altura=" + screen.height;

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //envia querystring como se fosse uma página normal
        oReq.open("GET", "atualizatamanho.php?" + querystring, true);

        //Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
        oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
                alert(oReq.responseText); //Pega resposta do servidor
            }
        };

        //Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
        oReq.send(null);
    }

    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        enviarTamanhoTela();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', enviarTamanhoTela);
    }
})();
</script>
```

E crie um novo arquivo chamado `atualizatamanho.php`, você pode pegar os dados assim:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['largura'], $_GET['altura'])) {
    $largura = $_GET['largura'];
    $altura = $_GET['altura'];

    var_dump($largura, $altura); //Pode remover essa linha

    //Resto do seu código aqui
}
```

Answer (score -6):

É que você esta tentando somar uma string com um inteiro.

tente converter a variável `$width`.
ex.

```
$width = (int) 10.9;

var_dump( $width );
```

Comment: Na verdade é um problema com o capacitor de fluxo do código dele.

Comment: Caramba! "Capacitor do fluxo do código"... Gastou agora

Comment: @Zooboomafoo o código é tipo back to the future, ele quer que o valor impresso pelo js volte no tempo e execute no php.