# Função PHP na action de um input text

Tags: php, html

É possível chamar uma função php dentro do parametro do action, do meu formulário?

```
    <!--FILTRO FLUTUANTE -->
<div id="mws-themer">
    <div id="mws-themer-hide"></div>
    <div id="mws-themer-content">
        <div class="mws-themer-section">
            <form action="<?php myFunction() ?>"  name="myForm" id="myForm" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="" class="mws-textinput error">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="mws-themer-separator"></div>
        <div class="mws-themer-section">
            <button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="mws-button red small" id="mws-themer-sendfilterPCD">Filtrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não é possível. PHP é uma linguagem do lado do servidor, o que você tá tentando fazer você conseguirá com Javascript por exemplo, que atua do lado do cliente, ou seja, na view/página que é apresentada pro usuário.

Answer (score 4):

Não é possivel, como já expliquei em uma postagem semelhante:

- [Quando somo uma variável que passei de JS para PHP ela soma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177047/3635)

PHP geralmente é server-side e no caso de sites, sempre é server-side, ou seja o PHP gera o HTML envia como resposta via internet de volta pra ti e então o teu navegador renderiza a resposta HTML na tela, ou seja a função PHP já foi processada:

[image: HTTP]

Pra resumir toda tecnologia web irá funcionar sob o protocolo HTTP, que tem requisições e respostas.

### Solução alternativa

A solução alternativa é criar uma chamada POST com if depois que o formulário é enviado, exemplo:

```
<form action="paginadestino.php" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="" class="mws-textinput error">
</form>
```

E na paginadestino.php (que pode ser um .php ou apenas uma página dinamica com querystring `?foo=baz`) adicione a IF:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['edtMFIR'])) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Se deseja que **não troque de página** só usando Ajax (o que muda toda a abordagem), por exemplo:

```
<form action="paginadestino.php" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="" class="mws-textinput error">
</form>

<script>
(function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        oReq.open(this.method, this.url, true);
        oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        //Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
        oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
                if (oReq.status => 200 && oReq < 300) {
                    alert(oReq.responseText); //Pega a resposta do servidor
                } else {
                    alert(oReq.status); //Pega o código de erro da resposta do lado do servidor
                }
            }
        };

        oReq.send(new FormData(this)); //Envia os campos do formulário

    });
})();
</script>
```

E no PHP também terá que ser:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['edtMFIR'])) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Então dentro das "IFs" você pode fazer o que desejar com JavaScript, **basta ajustar**:

```
if (oReq.status => 200 && oReq < 300) {
    //Faz algo com JavaScript se a resposta HTTP for "OK"
} else {
    //Faz algo com JavaScript se tiver ocorrido algum erro
}
```