# Inserir PHP em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá

Eu preciso pegar os resultados de um `SELECT` em `PHP` e exibir em um `ALERT` dentro de uma função em `JAVASCRIPT`, onde ao executar a função `JAVASCRIPT` roda o `PHP` e o `WHILE`. Como eu posso fazer ? Eu estou confuso quanto as chaves e a tag SCRIPT.

```html
<script>

function jsLoad( ) 
{

$("#preload").hide();
continuar_produtos();

}

function continuar_produtos()
{
</script>

<?php


//1. Dados de conex?o
$host = "localhost";
$bd = "bancodedadosr";
$usr = "root";
$psw = "12345";

//3. Cria a conex?o
$conn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $psw, $bd);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
die("A conex?o falhou, consulte o suporte: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//4. D? um SELECT no Banco de Dados utilizando os dados recebidos via POST
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, imagem, modelo FROM produtos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//5. D? um while e armazena na vari?vel o valor dos dados
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
//6.5. Criar n? filho (resultado)
$id = $row['id'];
$nome = $row['nome'];
$tipo = $row['tipo'];
$imagem = $row['imagem'];

?>

<script>

alert("<?php echo $nome; ?>");

</script>
   
<?php
 }
}
   
?>

<script>

}

function jsDivStore()

{

$("#store").show();

$( "#store" ).load( "new-product.php", function() {

});

}
```

Questão resolvida: Código funcionando:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="continuar_produtos()">
<script>
function jsLoad( ) 
{
$("#preload").hide();
continuar_produtos();
}

function continuar_produtos()
{

<?php
//1. Dados de conex?o
$host = "localhost";
$bd = "bancodedadosr";
$usr = "root";
$psw = "12345";

//3. Cria a conex?o
$conn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $psw, $bd);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
 die("A conex?o falhou, consulte o suporte: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//4. D? um SELECT no Banco de Dados utilizando os dados recebidos via POST
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, imagem, modelo FROM produtos";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 //5. D? um while e armazena na vari?vel o valor dos dados
 if ($result->num_rows > 0)
 {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $nome = $row['nome'];
    $tipo = $row['tipo'];
    $imagem = $row['imagem'];
    $modelo = $row['modelo'];
?>

alert("<?php echo $nome; ?>");

<?php
  }
 }
?>
}

function jsDivStore()
{
$("#store").show();

$( "#store" ).load( "new-product.php", function() {

});

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você que rodar o while do PHP como se fosse um JavaScript? Não tem como fazer isso. O PHP roda no servidor e volta como HTML.

Comment: Vai ter que usar AJAX, fazer uma requisição a uma página php com o javascript e retornar um Json para utilizalo.

Comment: Eu ja fiz isso uma vez, mas não lembro como fiz e não utilizei AJAX. Eu acho que botei o ALERT no meio do WHILE do PHP e foi exibindo no ALERT os resultados do SELECT.

Comment: Como responder à sua própria pergunta: [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

PHP não interage com front-end, chamar uma função JavaScript assim nunca vai funcionar:

```
function continuar_produtos()
{
<?php
//Codigo PHP aqui
?>
}
```

O PHP já foi executado antes da página ser renderizada na sua tela, ao executar `continuar_produtos` ele não vai executar o PHP novamente, ele só vai chamar algo que já foi processado, ou seja não tem sentido.

Em qualquer site, projeto web usa HTTP, não existe outro meio de comunicação, é requisição => servidor => processa PHP => download => renderiza.

Quase todos os dias vejo perguntas sobre executar PHP dentro de JavaScript, isso não funciona, nunca vai funcionar, não é um problema com PHP, é porque isso é Web e Web é HTTP e só funciona assim, mesmo que não fosse HTTP ainda sim é comunicação entre o computador do cliente com outro computador, logo não tem sentido funcionarem paralelamente.

Mais ou menos assim:

[image: modelo HTTP cliente-servidor]

Isso é o principio básico pra quem vai trabalhar com Web, se não sabe isso, então você não sabe o que é web e nem o que esta fazendo, resumindo não é uma critica, mas sim um conselho, aprenda o básico do HTTP, veja exemplos de perguntas:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/239158/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635

### Qual a solução?

Primeiro entender como funciona a comunicação entre duas máquinas e no caso de web aprender o básico do HTTP, os links que indiquei já ajudam um pouco e segundo é usar Ajax ou mudar a abordagem do seu código, no caso se for usar Ajax terá que criar um script a parte para executar esse processo.

Comment: O codigo que postei acima esta funcionando, eu misturei o php com javascript e deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Comentários no próprio código.

```
 //declaração do array
 $listStr = Array();

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $nome = $row['nome'];
   $tipo = $row['tipo'];
   $imagem = $row['imagem'];
   $modelo = $row['modelo'];
   // o array
   $listStr[] = $row["Name"];

 }


//repete o alert para cada elemento do array
foreach ($listStr as $val) {

   echo "<script>

   alert(\"$val\");

   </script>";

}
```

Comment: Muito legal seu código, mas eu já resolvi. Obrigado

Comment: Porquê a concatenação e `explode` ? Não era mais fácil ter usado diretamente um array com `$listStr[] = $row["nome"];` e `foreach($listStr as $val){` ?

Comment: Convém ter a declaração do array antes do `while`. [Exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abe813264dc206766000d08ffbf908d468e771f8) do que estou a tentar dizer.

Comment: Não afeta. No exemplo que coloquei funciona até com a `4.4.9`. É só experimentar

Comment: @Isac não sei onde você está vendo que meu script está diferente do que você sugere. :)

Comment: É isso, agora ficou bom!

Comment: @Isac valeu, vivendo e aprendendo

Comment: O codigo que postei esta funcionando, eu misturei php e javascript e deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function jsLoad( ) 
    {
        $("#preload").hide();
            continuar_produtos();
    }
    function continuar_produtos()
    {
        <?php $nome = '';?>
        <?php
            //1. Dados de conex?o
            $host = "localhost";
            $bd = "bancodedadosr";
            $usr = "root";
            $psw = "12345";

            //3. Cria a conex?o
            $conn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $psw, $bd);
            if ($conn->connect_error) 
            {
                die("A conex?o falhou, consulte o suporte: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
            //4. D? um SELECT no Banco de Dados utilizando os dados recebidos via POST
            $sql = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, imagem, modelo FROM produtos";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            //5. D? um while e armazena na vari?vel o valor dos dados
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {

                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                   //6.5. Criar n? filho (resultado)
                   $id = $row['id'];
                   $nome = $row['nome'];
                   $tipo = $row['tipo'];
                   $imagem = $row['imagem'];
                   print("<SCRIPT language=javascript>alert('".$nome."');</SCRIPT>");
                }
            }    
        ?>

        //alert(<?php print_r($nome); ?>);
    }
    function jsDivStore()
    {
        $("#store").show();

        $( "#store" ).load( "new-product.php", function() {

        });

    }
</script>
```

Não tenho certeza se é isso que você está falando.

Comment: Então, oque eu preciso é quando chamar a função CONTINUAR_PRODUTOS a cada resultado do SELECT exibe no ALERT em JAVASCRIPT. testei este codigo mas não funcionou, oque pode estar errado ?

Comment: Eu editei meu código no bloco do While adicionei um print com o alert.

Comment: O codigo que postei esta funcionando, eu misturei php e javascript e deu certo.