# como escrever corretamente o php dentro do javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde..
tenho a seguinte situação:

```
<?php

    $array_dias_da_semana = array("domingo", "segunda", "terca","quarta","quinta","sexta","sabado"); 
    $zebra = 'domingo';
?>

    $(function()
        {
            $('.button').click(function()
            {
                bb = $(this);
                $(".tab-content div").each(function( index ) 
                {
                    if($( this ).attr('class').indexOf('active') != -1)
                    {               
                        var vdia =  "<?php echo $array_dias_da_semana[index]?>";


                        alert(" B Indice: " + index+ ' value..: '+ $(bb).val()+ ' - vdia ' + vdia);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Não consigo escrever corretamente esta linha:

```
var vdia =  "<?php echo $array_dias_da_semana[index]?>";
```

Como devo escrever?????
Tenho o ARRAY em PHP  que contem 6 datas e a funçao em javascript que retorna o index da tab. 
Na linha acima como podem perceber o index é o retorno da function.
 Com o index eu gostaria de pegar a data no indice correspondente do ARRAY do PHP $array_dias_da_semana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira certa de escrever PHP dentro de JavaScript é evitar fazê-lo. Sei que soa a brincadeira mas é verdade. Eu próprio usei dessas misturas de linguagens mas isso gera uma quantidade enorme de bugs e é difícil de ler e manter.

Se precisas de passar informação do PHP para o JavaScript cria o mínimo pontos de contacto possível. Neste teu caso seria passares essa array no inicio.

No PHP:

```php
<?php
    $array_dias_da_semana = array("domingo", "segunda", "terca","quarta","quinta","sexta","sabado"); 
    $zebra = 'domingo';
?>
```

No JavaScript (com php numa linha só, no inicio):

```js
$(function() {
  var diasDaSemana = <?php echo json_encode($array_dias_da_semana); ?>;
  // assim a tua variável diasDaSemana fica ["domingo","segunda","terca","quarta","quinta","sexta","sabado"]
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(".tab-content div").each(function(index) {
      if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
        var vdia = diasDaSemana[i];

        alert(" B Indice: " + index + ' value..: ' + this.value + ' - vdia ' + vdia);

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ♦ Boa tarde. Obrigado pela atenção :). Com sua luz consegui obter o resultado pretendido com o json_enconde. Quando você fala de mistura de linguagens esta se referindo ao o que eu estava tentando fazer? tipo php dentro do javascript ou NÃO colocar javascript/ jquery dentro do sistema em php??

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza há _N_ maneiras de o fazer. Partilhar dados em JSON ou outras strings pode ser muito útil, e evita ajax. Se é possivel é bom usar. O problema é quando "espalhas" PHP dentro da lógica do JavaScript. A minha sugestão é "usar com moderação", separando claramente a lógica. O mesmo se aplica a fazer `echo` de pedaços de JavaScript no PHP. Fica dificil de manter e gera bugs. (respondi à tua pergunta?)

Comment: Entendi sim.. Mais uma vez.. Obrigado pela sua atenção.

Answer (score 3):

PHP não se comunica diretamente com o front-end, index é uma variavel do JavaScript e não do PHP, logo PHP já foi processado e já foi executado, o PHP vai procurar `index` como se fosse uma constante no PHP.

Ou seja não tem como fazer isto, semelhante ao que já respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635

Você tem que entender algumas coisas primeiro:

- **front-end**

  O front-end é um termo relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir ao que será processado no navegador
- **back-end**

  O back-end também relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir as tecnologias em geral do lado do servidor, como banco de dados, programa que processa o HTTP (como Apache e IIS) e linguagem dinâmica e frameworks

HTTP é mais ou menos isto:

[image: http]

Você irá precisar mudar a abordagem

Comment: Boa tarde.  Obrigado pela sua atenção :). Gostaria de sinalizar que com a "direção" do nosso colega Sergio conseguir obter o resultado desejado. Abraços :)

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza blz, a minha fica complemento para entender o funcionamento das aplicações web (comunicação HTTP)

Comment: Com certeza.. Já li os dois links que tu mencionou. Perfeitos :)