# PHP dentro do css é possível?

Tags: wordpress

Eu estou trocando a logo da tela de ligin do WordPress. Para isso eu estou usando o PHP para filtrar a função trocando o CSS. Só que como tenho vários serviços iguais a esse, preciso fazer isso de forma dinâmica, ou seja, usar o mesmo código para vários sites. Então vai ficar assim:

```
function my_f(){
echo '<style type="text/css">
   h1 a{background-image:url( php tem que ser aqui "exemplo: function();" )
   } 
</style>';
}
```

Isso está gerando um problama, porque o php está vendo isso como string.

Comment: talvez isso te interesse: https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logo/

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como executar uma função você pode pegar o `return` da função:

```
function funcaoDeExemplo() {
    return 'algo aqui.jpg';
}

function my_f(){
echo '<style type="text/css">
   h1 a{background-image:url(' . funcaoDeExemplo() .  ')
   } 
</style>';
}
```

Se o que deseja executar PHP na camada front-end não é possivel "diretamente", entenda mais sobre front-end e back-end primeiro:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635

Então a interação depende de outros meios ou mudar a abordagem completamente.