# Pegar variável de um PHP utilizando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu faço esse requisição com AJAX, porém quando dou `echo` na variável `$_GET` ela não exibe nada, dei um `print_r` e um `dump` nela e ela está vazia, é simplesmente um *array* vazio. Porém, no `sucess`, o `console.log` exibe os dados que quero pegar, porém quero essa variável em PHP e não estou conseguindo dessa forma.

```
<script>
$.get("request.php", "dados=dados", function(dados) {
  console.log(dados);
});
</script>
<?
$res = $_GET["dados"];
echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: No console aparece `dados`? Se sim, não ficou claro qual é o problema. Se o valor chega em `success`, o PHP está exibindo corretamente o valor. Como verificou que não chega dados no PHP?

Comment: No console ele exibe o valor que eu quero, porém quando dou $_GET["dados"] pra pegar o valor da variável ela fica vazia...

Comment: @rmiranda PHP é executado do lado do servidor. O $_GET é "executado" antes do Ajax. Tenha em mente que o PHP monta a página inteira antes de enviar para o cliente e é o cliente que executa o Ajax.

Comment: E esse código PHP fica onde? No arquivo `request.php`? Sabe que esta requisição que fez é assíncrona, certo?

Comment: Sim, amigo, fica no request.php. Mas quero trazer uma variável lá do request  para o index no caso e to fazendo esse get com essa finalidade, não sei se estou sendo claro...

Comment: @rmiranda está sendo claro, mas precisa entender os momentos onde o PHP trabalha e onde o Ajax trabalha. PHP não trabalha do lado do cliente, se precisar mostral algo com Ajax na mesma página, precisa usar JS. Se quiser pegar um dado via PHP, precisa fazer o Ajax executar este PHP e mostrar via JS, da mesma forma. O PHP não tem como modificar por si só o conteudo de uma página já enviada para o cliente, ele roda no servidor, antes da exibição.

Comment: Mesmo que você faça o request para a mesma página, o que está sendo exibido no echo é o da primeira execução. O dado da segunda execução será pego pelo GET seguinte, mas não aparecerá na tela.

Comment: Rmiranda Só pra teste, troque `<?` por `<?php`, (supondo que request.php tenha o js e o php ao mesmo tempo), todavia é como o @Bacco disse, talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635,
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635 e
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635 (Bacco se tiver algum link bom, talvez melhor, por favor indica pra mim, para uso futuro :D)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou meio que "de passagem" pelo site, creio que seus links podem ajudar um bocado. De momento, não lembro de nada específico sobre o assunto (sei que já tratamos disso antes, mas não consigo lembrar de imediato como achar). Aproveitem pra conferir se eu não pulei nenhum detalhe nos comentarios :)

Comment: @Bacco Entendi, mas de que forma eu faria para executar o GET da forma que você disse? Eu achei q só de colocá-lo sequencialmente depois já não teria esse problema de ordem de execução...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pela sugestão, mas não funcionou...

Comment: Dentro da *callback* `success` você já tem o valor que deseja no JavaScript. O PHP ali não funcionará da maneira que você quer. Para entender isso, leia todas as perguntas e respostas listadas pelo Guilherme. No momento que você fez a requisição você está trabalhando no lado do cliente, não mais do servidor, então esqueça o PHP.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Então o que eu estou tentando fazer não é possível? Pegar uma variável de um .php com ajax?

Comment: É possível e você já fez. Tanto que em `success` chega o valor que você quer. Só não está claro o que você precisa fazer com esse valor, então não tem como te ajudar em mais detalhes que isso.

Comment: @rmiranda leia os links que passei no comentário anterior, mas leia com calma, bem provavel que você não tenha entendido o back-end e front-end e aonde eles se localizam, o mais importante é você entender as "camadas".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Então, amigo preciso manipular esse valor na página que estou, por isso dei o $_GET[]. O que não ficou claro pra mim, é como pegar o valor do success e passar para o meu PHP.

Comment: Não passa. Qualquer coisa que você precisará fazer com este valor agora será com JavaScript, pois você está no lado do cliente, não mais no servidor.

Comment: Só me responde uma coisa, o teu `$.get(...)` esta no mesmo arquivo que request.php? Creio que não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não está, Guilherme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que tudo isso seja apenas uma **confusão** de sua parte.

**Se** `request.php` for um arquivo e o teu jQuery e scripts esteverem em outra página, pois se estivessem tudo no mesmo arquivo, o retorno da variável `dados` no `function` iria mostrar no console algo como **isto tudo**:

[image: assim]

**Sim, ele retornaria até o javascript e o html** como uma `string`, pois a página atual estaria requisitando ela mesma, mas se não retornou isto então é porque são diferentes páginas e diferentes scripts PHP, se este for o caso é bem provável que você não esteja apontando um arquivo corretamente.

### Teste prático com `$.get` (`$.ajax`):

Crie os seguintes arquivos:

**foo.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

**baz.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Oi</p>

<script>
$.get("foo.php", "dados=dados", function(dados) {
    console.log(dados);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ambos devem ficar na mesma pasta e não deve alterar nada, o resultado que fiz retornou exatamente isto:

[image: teste Ajax no Opera]

Outros possiveis problemas:

### Versão do jQuery com BUG

Talvez em sua página você esteja usando uma versão do jQuery que tenha algum bug (já ocorreu comigo), recomendo que atualize para a ultima versão (no caso pode escolher entre as *major* versões jQuery1, jQuery2, ou jQuery3), no caso eu uso o 1.12.4:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Para outras versões veja: http://jquery.com/download/

### Problema de algum plugin que esta usando `ajaxSetup`

Se por acaso estiver usando [`$.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) ele pode afetar o comportamento de todas chamadas jQuery, recomendo que remova se existir e teste novamente.

Como teste faça isto:

```
$.get("request.php?dados=dados", function(dados) {
    console.log(dados);
});
```

E veja se ainda falha

### Problema na instalação do PHP e Apache

Para ter certeza se é problema na instalação do servidor para você poder tirar uma prova real tente acessar `request.php` diretamente, por exemplo:

- http://localhost/pasta/request.php?dados=dados

Se funcionar dificilmente o problema será na instalação do servidor.

### Você não entendeu o que é HTTP

Como eu pedi, você poderia ler os links que tentei explicar o melhor que consegui sobre como funciona Requisições e Respostas, penso eu que você deve estar fazendo confusão nisto e se ler com calma os links vai entender bem aonde esta falhando, isto porque HTML e JavaScript não se "comunicam diretamente" com o PHP:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635

Resumindo um pouco:

você tem que entender algumas coisas primeiro:

- **front-end**

  O front-end é um termo relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir ao que será processado no navegador
- **back-end**

  O back-end também relativo, mas na pratica ele geralmente é usado para se referir as tecnologias em geral do lado do servidor, como banco de dados, programa que processa o HTTP (como Apache e IIS) e linguagem dinamica e frameworks
- **Requisição HTTP**

  É o que o navegador envia para um servidor, ocorre no momento que você digita um URL na barra de navegação, quando envia um upload
- **Resposta HTTP**

  A resposta HTTP é gerada após uma requisição HTTP e ele irá responder conforme o pedido desta requisição

O PHP é uma linguagem que pode ser usada (e geralmente é usada) para páginas web, ela roda do lado que chamamos "back-end", o navegador se comunica com o servidor através do protocolo HTTP fazendo uma requisição, então o PHP processa um script e gera uma resposta, isto tudo ocorre no servidor e não na maquina do usuário, a cada linha ou conteúdo completo gerado será enviado como "resposta HTTP" para o navegador que requisitou, por exemplo:

[image: http]

Ou seja PHP não roda junto ao HTML, ele gera uma resposta que pode ser um "documento" HTML, como pode ser um TXT, uma image, um video, vai depender do que você definiu que o PHP deve enviar de resposta.

**Eu sei** que as respostas linkadas não resolvem o teu problema, só que o teu problema provavelmente é a sua confusão por não entender as camadas.

Comment: A última frase respondeu tudo. Acho que eu entendi o que ele estava tentando fazer e, de fato, foi uma confusão. Os arquivos são diferentes e a requisição foi feita corretamente - entendendo o que estava acontecendo, mas acredito que a confusão estava na resposta HTTP. O `echo $_GET["dados"]` dele no PHP estava no `index.php` e estava assim pois ele acreditava que o valor `dados` enviado pela requisição seria retornado pela resposta ao arquivo `index.php` e, assim, exibir novamente `dados` na tela. Como comentou, ele não entendeu HTTP e *[client/server]-side*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é um erro tão comum, por isso insisto nos links que apontei naquele comentário, eu tinha um link melhor que era só sobre o assunto, mas nem lembro mais aonde esta (talvez tenha sido no SOen)

Comment: Valeuzão, Guilherme Nascimento!
Agora entendi, eu fiz uma confusão aqui mesmo, rs
Só perguntei aqui pq não consegui ajuda em outro lugar, mas obrigado!

Comment: @rmiranda quando puder marque a resposta como correta, se ela resolveu teu problema.

Answer (score -2):

Tente enviar assim pra ver o que acontece

```
  <script>
    $.get( "request.php",
           { dados: "dados" }, 
           function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
       }  );
    </script>
```

E no php:

```
<?php
  $dados = $_GET['dados'];
  echo $dados;
?>
```

Comment: Na pergunta está explícito que o `console.log` exibe corretamente os valores. Ou seja, o problema não está neste código. Por favor, preste um pouco mais atenção antes de responder e veja os comentários o que já foi discutido.

Comment: Só pra constar, não fui eu quem negativou, tanto que entendi sua sugestão, todavia o `$.get` aceita tanto string quanto object, o problema deve ser uma confusão do usuário.

Answer (score -3):

Vamos ver se eu entendi, você está em uma página em PHP, querendo fazer uma requisição assíncrona para outra página em PHP, isso?

Porque não utilizar o cURL.

$curl = curl_init( "request.php?dados=dados" );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );

$response = curl_exec( $curl );

$error = curl_error( $curl );

curl_close( $curl );