# Mudar documento de HTML para PHP

Tags: php, html, extensão

Gente, como eu faço pra transformar um arquivo HTML para PHP? É só mudar a extensão? É correto fazer assim? Aparentemente, meu servidor leu a página que eu mudei de HTML para PHP, mas tenho dúvidas se está certo ou não, afinal de contas, eu só mudei a extensão de *.html* para *.php*.

Comment: Precisa ter o apache instalado no seu servidor se não o código php vai vira texto na hora da exibição.

Comment: só mudar a extensão de html para php, já que seu servidor roda php, não há problema algum.

Comment: @rray se não houver apache tanto o código php quanto o html também vira texto, certo?

Comment: As respostas HTTP geradas pelo seus PHPs podem ser qualquer coisa, como: json, imagem, html, txt, etc. PHP não é o "equivalente" ao HTML, apenas é possivel escrever HTML no meio dele que será processado e enviado ao via download como se fosse um HTML puro, após processado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mikaela, imagine que você tenha um arquivo chamado `index.html` com o conteúdo descrito abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aprendendo HTML e PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Prazer, me chamo Godfrey the King.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Você como uma pessoa curiosa, decidiu mudar a extensão para `.php`.

Ao abrir a página em seu navegador - **lembrando que você precisa ter um servidor web instalado em seu computador, qual é facilmente instalado utilizando o XAMPP, WAMP, EasyPHP, entre outros.** - surgirá a seguinte frase:

`"Prazer, me chamo Godfrey the King."`

Se você mudar um pouco o código, para:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aprendendo HTML e PHP</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php $nome = "Mikaela"; ?>

        <p>Prazer, me chamo <?php echo $nome; ?>.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

A frase será trocada por: `"Prazer, me chamo Mikaela.".`

Agora faça um pequeno teste e mude a extensão do arquivo para `.html` novamente e recarregue a página.

Notou a diferença?

---

> HTML é uma linguagem de marcação utilizada na construção de páginas na
>   Web.  Documentos HTML podem ser *interpretados por navegadores*.
>
> PHP é uma linguagem interpretada livre, usada originalmente apenas
>   para o desenvolvimento de aplicações presentes e atuantes no lado do
>   servidor. Scripts PHP são *interpretados no lado do servidor*.

Comment: sim sim, isso eu entendi, vou detalhar um pouco mais...
Eu criei um site em html, todo ele em html5 e css3;
como eu estou aprendendo, decidi adicionar um login e senha nele, com banco de dados, ou seja, acrescentar php e mysql, eu tenho o servidor xampp no meu computador, e a única coisa que eu fiz, fui mudar a terminação do meu arquivo de html para php, acessei pelo localhost, e ele abriu o arquivo php normalmente, da mesma forma que ele abria em html, eu ainda não adicionei nada em php, a pergunta é, vai dar problema no site na hora que eu hospedar ele online se eu deixar ele assim?

Comment: @MikaelaKleinkauf Não, não vai. O que você não pode, é esquecer de colocar o código `PHP` dentro da tag  `<?php ?>` - por exemplo - quando você for escrever código `PHP`.

Comment: Como eu disse em minha resposta, tudo o que você escrever dentro de tags do `PHP` será interpretado pelo seu servidor web (no seu caso o `apache`) e assim "devolvido" para o seu navegador exibir os dados.

Comment: @MikaelaKleinkauf Se sanei suas dúvidas, não esqueça de marcar como correta a resposta.

Comment: sim sim, era essa a minha dúvida ^^ muito muuuuiiittoooo obrigada =D

Comment: @MikaelaKleinkauf Então se possível, aceite minha resposta como correta. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 0):

É apenas fazer isso, mudando para php você faz o seu servidor entender que aquela página têm códigos em php. Se você tentar, por exemplo, executar um código php com um arquivo *.html, nada vai ocorrer, apenas irá imprimir um texto na tela com o seu código.

Answer (score 0):

A mudança de extensão só apresentará problema se na página precisar executar alguma instrução em **`PHP`**.

Exemplo de página de código que não terá problema nas duas extensões:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

O "Hello World!" abaixo só será apresentado se estiver com a extensão em **`PHP`**:

```
<h1><?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?></h1>
```

> Para que o código **`PHP`** seja executado deve estar num servidor Web
>   preparado, como o Apache por exemplo.

Comment: É bem essa a minha dúvida, eu tenho o apache instalado, e mudei somente a extensão de html para php; no meu localhost, exibiu exatamente igual, da mesma forma que exibia com terminação html, eu ainda não inseri nada em php, mas vou colocar php dentro do documento, eu vou ter que colocar echo em todo o documento?

Comment: @MikaelaKleinkauf Não. O _echo_ apenas imprime texto na tela dentro do código PHP `<?php ?>`. Qualquer outro texto na tela vc faz igual a um arquivo HTML.

Comment: então o meu documento html vai funcionar bem se eu mudar para php?

Comment: Se a página vai ter códigos em `PHP` é necessário que esteja nessa extensão. Nos lugares que são conteúdos fixos não há a necessidade de colocar o `echo`, pode deixar o texto simples dentro da tag HTML. Funcionará corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar é só trocar a extensão do arquivo, não esqueça de colocar o arquivo .php em um servidor Apache (pode utilizar xampp, wampp... para teste)

Comment: foi exatamente isso que eu fiz =D

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro é necessário entender o que é front-end e back-end, estas perguntas devem ajudar:

- [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-c%C3%B3digo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635

Então é assim que funciona, a sua máquina/navegador requisitam via HTTP uma página em teu site, o PHP não é executado na sua maquina, ele é um script que gera uma resposta HTTP e envia via download para a sua máquina correspondente a requisição, algo como estas ilustrações:

[image: http]

e

[image: http]

Ou seja o PHP processa uma resposta que é um HTML e dependendo da configuração do servidor a extensão `.php` nem irá existir, isto é apenas uma maneira que a linguagem usa para facilitar a criação de páginas.

As respostas HTTP geradas pelo seus PHPs podem ser qualquer coisa, como: json, imagem, html, txt, etc.