# Enviando dados para Controller via Ajax LARAVEl

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-rotas

Estou com um projeto no qual tenho que enviar o CPF de um paciente para uma método na controller afim de fazer uma busca dentro desse método e já retornar o valor da busca para a view , porem não estou conseguindo enviar esses valor para a view.

**Atualização**
já estou conseguindo acessar a controller e retornardo o objeto para  o ajax porem ainda não estou conseguindo acessar no ajax. não aparece nenhum erro e consigo verificar  no network que o metodo da controller esta retornando os dados corretamente.
**segue novo código atualizado:**

**controller**

```
public function verificarCadastro (Request $request){

     return \Response::json($this->paciente->where('cpf',$request->cpf)->get());        

}
```

**ajax na view**

```
    function buscarCpf() {

    cpf = $('#cpfBusca').val();



    $.ajax({

        url: window.location.href+"/verificar-cadastro", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {"cpf": cpf,"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}" },
        cache: false,
        processData: true,
        dateType:'json',
        sucess: function(data) {

            if(data.cpf != null)
                console.log(data.cpf);

        },
        erro: function(data){

            console.log(data);
        }       

    });
              //window.location.href = caminho;


     };
```

**retorno que esta vindo no network**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

PHP é back-end, ele processa e gera páginas, seja HTML, seja txt, seja imagem, etc...

A variável `data` é JavaScript e por sua vez é processada no front-end, bem depois da página HTML ter sido gerada pelo PHP+Laravel, você não vai conseguir jogar a variável `data` em algo que **"já foi processado"!**:

```
"{{ URL::route('hospedagem.registrar',data) }}";
```

Ou seja, não tem como passar uma variável JavaScript para o PHP diretamente, como expliquei em:

- [Quando somo uma variável que passei de JS para PHP ela soma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635)
- [Detectar ou bloquear redirecionamento com ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635)

Comment: como posso estar solucionando esse caso então?

Comment: @MárcioCésar você pode usar Session no back-end (no Laravel) ou querystring no `window.location`, mas vai depender do que as suas rotas fazem, não tem como dar uma resposta precisa porque nem tenho ideia de como esta o seu código.

Comment: editei o código gostaria que desse uma olhada

Comment: @MárcioCésar você só mudou a parte do JavaScript e postou apenas parte do controller, no caso o `verificarCadastro`, da maneira que esta eu nem consigo saber por onde começar, eu preciso entender pra onde quer enviar os dados do JSON. Entende?

Comment: então eu to fazendo uma verificacao para saber se o cadastro existe no caso se retornar o json no sucess: do ajax e eu conseguir ao menos rodar o console.log() na minha tela com os dados que to pedindo ja sanaria minha duvida, porem ele n retorna nada ali no sucess e nem no erro, mas os dados estão sendo enviados pela controller como pode verificar no network que coloquei na imagem

Comment: @MárcioCésar entendo, mas e o `window.location`? Por favor leia este link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e tente revisar a pergunta, porque você mudou o contexto da pergunta e ainda sim não explicou bem o que fez, eu realmente quero ajudar, mas não tem como entender assim. Recomendo que siga as recomendações e com certeza conseguirei lhe ajudar.

Comment: consegui resolver o problema fazendo uma correção simples no codigo o nome sucess estava errado : o correto é success.