# Como pegar o valor do input em tempo real?

Tags: php, html, input, tempo-real

Eu tenho esse input que está oculto e desativado:

```
<input type="text" disabled="" id="valorMascara" class="oculto" name="valorMascara">
```

existe dois inputs type radio que envia valor pro input oculto, quero pegar o valor desse input em tempo real e jogar dentro de uma variavel em **PHP**, **SEM DAR SUBMIT, SEM ENVIAR O FORM, QUERO PEGAR EM TEMPO REAL**.

Comment: Não tem como alterar variável PHP via client-side.

Comment: As respostas dadas já dão a solução: vai ter que gastar uma requisição pro servidor tratar o valor da variável e devolver a resposta pro navegador. O JavaScript vai preencher o campo sem necessidade de recarregar a página. Tudo, teoricamente, "em tempo real".

Comment: Dentro da "variavel PHP" não tem como, PHP roda no lado do servidor e quando a pagina renderiza o PHP já foi carregado e terminado. ou seja não há mais interação direta. web é isso, requisições e respostas HTTP. Como eu já expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102460/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você irá precisar de js, será algo assim:

```
$('#iddoinput').keyup(function(){

   var text = $(this).val();
   alert(text);
   //Aqui dentro você faz o que quer, manda pra um arquivo php com ajax
   //ou sla, vai depender do que você quer fazer

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer através de uma requisição AJAX:

O script que você poderia usar no lado do cliente seria:

```
$('#id-do-input').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $.post('update.php', {
    param: $this.val()
  }, alert('Enviado!'));
});
```

E no lado do servidor:

```
<?php

$param = $_POST['param'];

if (! $param) {
  echo 'Nada foi recebido.';
  exit;
}

// Do stuff...

echo 'Dados recebidos!';
```